# IOS App crashes - unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, exception

In tableView:cellForRowAtIndexpath method, my code is as below.

When I comment out the if condition enclosed in double asterisk(*), the app crashes with the exception mentioned below. And if I uncomment it then it works fine. Please help as I am new to Objective-C.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @“MyTableCell";

    cell = (MyTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@“MyTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    **if (invoiceList.count == indexPath.row  + 1)**
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *currentDictionary = [invoiceList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];        
        cell.invoiceDetails = currentDictionary;

        for ( NSString *key in [cell.invoiceDetails allKeys]) {
            NSString *value = [cell.invoiceDetails valueForKey:key];

            if([key isEqualToString:MERCHANT_NAME]){
                cell.merchantNameValue.text  = (value == (id)[NSNull null]) ? @"" : value;
            }

            if([key isEqualToString:INVOICE_ID]){
                cell.invoiceIdValue.text  = (value == (id)[NSNull null]) ? @"" : value;
            }

            if([key isEqualToString:TOTAL_AMOUNT]){
                cell.totalAmountValue.text  = (value == (id)[NSNull null]) ? @"" : value;
            }
        }
    }

    return cell;

}
```

Exception thrown is:

```
-[__NSDictionaryM objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc2a604e9f0
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryM objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc2a604e9f0'

*** First throw call stack:

(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fbd1f35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010f63ebb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fbd904d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fb3127c ___forwarding___ + 988
4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fb30e18 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   MobileWalletBanking                 0x000000010cf0037f -[MyViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 479
6   UIKit                               0x000000010dd9b4b3 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 508
7   UIKit                               0x000000010dd7afb1 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2846
8   UIKit                               0x000000010dd90e3c -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 213
9   UIKit                               0x000000010dd1d973 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 521
10  QuartzCore                          0x000000010d2bade8 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 150
...    
)
```

**EDIT:**
NSLog of invoiceList:

```
{
    501 = 72;
    610 = Merchant1;
    611 = Merchant1;
    612 = 51573;
    615 = 51573;
    616 = "07/08/2015 00:00:00";
    617 = "64.01";
    618 = 498;
    619 = 498;
    662 =     (
                {
            501 = 72;
            520 = "15.18";
            615 = 51573;
            616 = "07/08/2015 00:00:00";
            620 = 43;
            621 = "15.18";
            623 = True;
            624 = 43;
            740 = “Text1";
        },
                {
            501 = 72;
            520 = 0;
            615 = 51573;
            616 = "07/08/2015 00:00:00";
            620 = 10;
            621 = 0;
            623 = True;
            624 = 10;
            740 = “Text2";
        },
                {
            501 = 72;
            520 = "37.63";
            615 = 51573;
            616 = "07/08/2015 00:00:00";
            620 = 2;
            621 = "37.63";
            623 = True;
            624 = 2;
            740 = “Text3";
        },
                {
            501 = 72;
            520 = "11.20";
            615 = 51573;
            616 = "07/08/2015 00:00:00";
            620 = 3;
            621 = "11.20";
            623 = True;
            624 = 3;
            740 = “Text4";
        },
                {
            501 = 72;
            520 = 0;
            615 = 51573;
            616 = "07/08/2015 00:00:00";
            620 = 14;
            621 = 0;
            623 = True;
            624 = 14;
            740 = “Text5";
        }
    );
    663 =     (
                (
                        {
                Key = 501;
                Value = 83;
            },
                        {
                Key = Name;
                Value = "INVOICE_CONNECTION_PROPERTIES";
            },
                        {
                Key = 611;
                Value = Merchant1;
            },
                        {
                Key = 610;
                Value = "";
            },
                        {
                Key = 615;
                Value = 51573;
            },
                        {
                Key = 620;
                Value = 1;
            },
                        {
                Key = "SERVICE_NAME";
                Value = “Text1";
            },
                        {
                Key = "FIELD_1";
                Value = 4272035;
            },
                        {
                Key = "FIELD_1_CONNECTION_FIELD_ID";
                Value = 000000000000481;
            },
                        {
                Key = "FIELD_1_QS_NAME";
                Value = "Id";
            },
                        {
                Key = "FIELD_1_QS_VALUE";
                Value = "Id";
            },
                        {
                Key = "FIELD_2";
                Value = 10;
            },
                        {
                Key = "FIELD_2_CONNECTION_FIELD_ID";
                Value = 000000000000482;
            },
                        {
                Key = "FIELD_2_QS_NAME";
                Value = "index1";
            },
                        {
                Key = "FIELD_2_QS_VALUE";
                Value = "index1";
            },
                        {
                Key = "FIELD_3";
                Value = "";
            },
                        {
                Key = "FIELD_3_IS_MODIFIED";
                Value = 1;
            },
                        {
                Key = "FIELD_3_CONNECTION_FIELD_ID";
                Value = 000000000000483;
            },
                        {
                Key = "FIELD_3_QS_NAME";
                Value = "index2";
            },
                        {
                Key = "FIELD_3_QS_VALUE";
                Value = "index2";
            },
                        {
                Key = "FIELD_4";
                Value = R;
            },
                        {
                Key = "FIELD_4_CONNECTION_FIELD_ID";
                Value = 000000000000488;
            },
                        {
                Key = "FIELD_4_QS_NAME";
                Value = "index_Type";
            },
                        {
                Key = "FIELD_4_QS_VALUE";
                Value = "Index_Type";
            }
        ),
                (
                        {
                Key = 501;
                Value = 83;
            },
                        {
                Key = Name;
                Value = "INVOICE_CONNECTION_PROPERTIES";
            },
                        {
                Key = 611;
                Value = Merchant1;
            },
                        {
                Key = 610;
                Value = "";
            },
                        {
                Key = 615;
                Value = 51573;
            },
                        {
                Key = 620;
                Value = 2;
            },
                        {
                Key = "SERVICE_NAME";
                Value = “Text2";
            },
                        {
                Key = "FIELD_1";
                Value = 4272033;
            },
                        {
                Key = "FIELD_1_CONNECTION_FIELD_ID";
                Value = 000000000000481;
            },
                        {
                Key = "FIELD_1_QS_NAME";
                Value = "Id";
            },
                        {
                Key = "FIELD_1_QS_VALUE";
                Value = "Id";
            },
                        {
                Key = "FIELD_2";
                Value = 3;
            },
                        {
                Key = "FIELD_2_CONNECTION_FIELD_ID";
                Value = 000000000000482;
            },
                        {
                Key = "FIELD_2_QS_NAME";
                Value = "index1";
            },
                        {
                Key = "FIELD_2_QS_VALUE";
                Value = "index1";
            },
                        {
                Key = "FIELD_3";
                Value = "";
            },
                        {
                Key = "FIELD_3_IS_MODIFIED";
                Value = 1;
            },
                        {
                Key = "FIELD_3_CONNECTION_FIELD_ID";
                Value = 000000000000483;
            },
                        {
                Key = "FIELD_3_QS_NAME";
                Value = "index2";
            },
                        {
                Key = "FIELD_3_QS_VALUE";
                Value = "index2";
            },
                        {
                Key = "FIELD_4";
                Value = C;
            },
                        {
                Key = "FIELD_4_CONNECTION_FIELD_ID";
                Value = 000000000000488;
            },
                        {
                Key = "FIELD_4_QS_NAME";
                Value = "index_type";
            },
                        {
                Key = "FIELD_4_QS_VALUE";
                Value = "index_type";
            }
        )
    );
    664 =     (
                (
                        {
                Key = 501;
                Value = 73;
            },
                        {
                Key = 625;
                Value = 000000000000481;
            },
                        {
                Key = 611;
                Value = Merchant1;
            },
                        {
                Key = 626;
                Value = "id";
            },
                        {
                Key = 627;
                Value = 1;
            },
                        {
                Key = 590;
                Value = True;
            }
        ),
                (
                        {
                Key = 501;
                Value = 73;
            },
                        {
                Key = 625;
                Value = 000000000000482;
            },
                        {
                Key = 611;
                Value = Merchant1;
            },
                        {
                Key = 626;
                Value = "index1";
            },
                        {
                Key = 627;
                Value = 2;
            },
                        {
                Key = 590;
                Value = True;
            }
        ),
                (
                        {
                Key = 501;
                Value = 73;
            },
                        {
                Key = 625;
                Value = 000000000000483;
            },
                        {
                Key = 611;
                Value = Merchant1;
            },
                        {
                Key = 626;
                Value = "index2";
            },
                        {
                Key = 627;
                Value = 3;
            },
                        {
                Key = 590;
                Value = True;
            }
        ),
                (
                        {
                Key = 501;
                Value = 73;
            },
                        {
                Key = 625;
                Value = 000000000000488;
            },
                        {
                Key = 611;
                Value = Merchant1;
            },
                        {
                Key = 626;
                Value = "index_type";
            },
                        {
                Key = 627;
                Value = 4;
            },
                        {
                Key = 590;
                Value = True;
            }
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of `indexPath+1` condition ? is `invoiceList` your data array? Post your `numberOfRows` method code too.

Comment: Are you sure that the exception is definitely happening at the objectAtIndex line you've shown us? Print the class of invoiceList beforehand: NSLog(@"%@",[invoiceList class])

Comment: can you provide the invoice list NSLog

Comment: Hello all, there is no special purpose of indexPath+1 condition. However with this condition, code does not throw any exception and runs perfectly. I have also provided invoiceList NSLog under EDIT section. Thanks for your support.

Comment: The above code with UITableView is written on First ViewController. when the user selects a row in UITableView and presses Next button its detail is shown on the second ViewController. Suppose only one row is selected and  the Next button is clicked, viewDidLoad method of the second ViewController is called and once it is done, runtime also calls cellForRowAtIndexPath of the first ViewController. At this time, it throws exception and numberOfRowsInSection method returns 12 in place of 1. I am not able to understand why numberOfRowsInSection returns 12. It should return 1 instead. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if (invoiceList.count == indexPath.row  + 1) but instead of it, use if (invoiceList.count> indexPath.row ). Please also check "numberOfRowsInIndexpath" is returning as invoiceList.count.

Comment: numberOfRowsInIndexpath is returning invoiceList.count. But the problem is if the if condition is uncommented then the same code works correctly.

Comment: invoiceList is this dictionary or array ?